# id(number) path in urls

Tags: python, django, url

I am new to django

In urls.py, I set path like this. I tried to create a page with urls: localhost:8000/topics/1/

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/', views.topic, name='topic'),
]
```

In views.py. Code is this:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, "entries": entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

I got error 404 when enter localhost:8000/topics/1/.

topics/(?P\d+)/ [name='topic']

The current path, topics/1/, didn't match any of these.

But the correct urls turns out to be: localhost:8000/topics/(%3FP1%5Cd+)/

Is there something wrong with the path in urls or what's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('topics/<topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
]
```

If you are **expecting an integer**, you could specify it as,

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
]
```

Why `topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/'` is not working?

Actually you are mixing the usage.

If you are trying yo provide a ***regex included expression in your urls***, use [**`re_path()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path).

So your pattern will be:

```py
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/', views.topic, name='topic'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, It works! But is mine the old version so that it no longer work? I was following a tutorial in a book.

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: My Django version is 2.1.4. I meant is the form 'topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/' no longer works in new version?